# Can IBM Websphere MQ client be used without installing

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to use IBM Websphere MQ client v7.5. I am writing standalone JMS client application to send and consume messages from the IBM WebsphereMQ server(which is running somewhere else but I have authority to send/receive messages)
I followed steps below:

1. Installed Websphere MQ client(Free version for 6 months) and did all basic installation.
2. I copied required Jar to other location/host and wrote a sample JMS application to send/receive messages. I am able to communicate to with the server.

My questions is : Can I use these Jars independently on any host(even in production) for life long or I should buy proper licence, install the client and then use those JARs ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: The client is permanently free. Where did you find one that is only free for 6 months?

Answer (score 5):

MQ v8.0.0.4 provides exactly what you want. See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21969244. Look for `IBM MQ JMS and Java 'All Client'`. Client is free but whoever runs the queue manager must have appropriate licenses.

Comment: But what will be the problem in v7.5 ? I can use it currently on any of my hosts without setting any env variable or running any command. I directly copy these jars from one to other hosts and run my java application, it's working absolutely fine.

Comment: I understand that it will work. But that sort of things are not officially supported by IBM. If there is a problem you will have recreate the same problem under full client installation. So why not go for MQ v8.0.0.4 which is fully supported by IBM.

Comment: The standard MQ Client is free at version 7.5 too, you don't need a license to install it. You only need a license for the extended transactional client.

Comment: Bear in mind that 'free' and 'supported' are not the same thing. Whether or not it works with V7.5 is not the point. Are you using something that will be supported by IBM should a problem occur is the point.